# Keras Network is not learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to learn how to make neural networks with Keras but the network doesn't learn.

This is my test were it should just learn to output the input and this doesn't even work. I've just copied the X data into the Y data and fed that into the training.

The loss and accuracy don't change even when I let it run for 1000 epoch or more.

```
import os
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"]="3"
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
import numpy

gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices("GPU")
if gpus:
    try:
        # Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
        for gpu in gpus:
            tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
        logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices("GPU")
        print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
    except RuntimeError as e:
        # Memory growth must be set before GPUs have been initialized
        print(e)

# Input
X_daten = [
    [-4],
    [-3],
    [-2],
    [-1],
    [ 0],
    [ 1],
    [ 2],
    [ 3],
    [ 4]
]
Y_daten = X_daten.copy()

test_anzahl = 2

X_train = numpy.array(X_daten[:-test_anzahl])
Y_train = numpy.array(Y_daten[:-test_anzahl])
X_test  = numpy.array(X_daten[-test_anzahl:])
Y_test  = numpy.array(Y_daten[-test_anzahl:])

print("1 X_train ", X_train.shape)
print("1 Y_train ", Y_train.shape)
print("1 X_test  ", X_test.shape)
print("1 Y_test  ", Y_test.shape)
print("-"*20)

X_train = numpy.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
Y_train = numpy.reshape(Y_train, (Y_train.shape[0], 1, Y_train.shape[1]))
X_test  = numpy.reshape(X_test , ( X_test.shape[0], 1,  X_test.shape[1]))
Y_test  = numpy.reshape(Y_test , ( Y_test.shape[0], 1,  Y_test.shape[1]))

print("2 X_train ", X_train.shape)
print("2 Y_train ", Y_train.shape)
print("2 X_test  ", X_test.shape)
print("2 Y_test  ", Y_test.shape)
print("-"*20)

# Neural Netzwerk
neuronen      = 100
layer         = 2
batch_size    = 10
epoch         = 1000
input_anzahl  = 1
output_anzahl = 1
#dropout       = 0.3
activation    = "sigmoid"
optimizer     = "Adam"

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(neuronen, input_shape=(None, input_anzahl), activation=activation))

for _ in range(layer):
    model.add(Dense(neuronen, activation=activation))
    #model.add(Dropout(dropout))

model.add(Dense(output_anzahl, activation=activation)) # Output

model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=optimizer, metrics=["accuracy"])

# Training
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epoch, verbose=1, shuffle=True,         validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

# Predict
print("\n" + "-"*100)
for i in range(len(X_daten)):
    daten = numpy.array([[X_daten[i]]])
    daten = numpy.reshape(daten, (daten.shape[0], 1, daten.shape[1]))

    ergebnis = model.predict(daten)

    print(" Ergebnis ", ergebnis, " \tY_daten[" + str(i) + "] ", Y_daten[i], " \tX_daten[" + str(i)     + "] ", X_daten[i])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest starting by making your activations "linear."  I believe Sigmoid is restricted to the range (0,+1) which is preventing the network from generating values that are close to the targets.  This may get you started in the right direction.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you that helped me :)